# How to use csv and Javascript together

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, csv

Hi I am trying to create a JavaScript program that extracts data from a csv sheet and puts this data into an array. I have installed a jquery library to help me with this, but as this is a first for me, wasn't sure how to implement the methods. Wondering if anyone can give background information on how to use this method:

```
var data = $.csv.toObjects(csv):
```

Does this need to be under a function that contains the url/path for the csv file. such as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
$.ajax({
    url: "C:\Users\Desktop\tester excel.csv",

    success: function (csvd) {
        data = $.csv.toArrays(csvd);
    },
```

And is there a way to test the program to ensure it is putting the inputs in an array (such as seeing it print out) any help appreciated JavaScript is very new to me.

Comment: `async: false` It's very rare that you'd want to do a synchronous request because this will block the UI until the request completes. Are you sure you want this?

Comment: `async:false` is deprecated. in 2018 there's *no* reason you should want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

AS for the [GitHub documentation](https://github.com/evanplaice/jquery-csv) you are right. Fetch via Ajax first, and then send the result to $.csv.

Btw it's better to work with a server-side programming language such as PHP as they better implement stuff like this.

Comment: JavaScript is also a server side programming language.

Comment: @BlackJack what would that mean? He is not talking about server-side javascript but clearly about front-end usage, so your answer is correct but unappropriate and useless at all..

Comment: _You_ were talking about working with a server side language such as PHP. I just wanted to point out that JavaScript also is a server side language, so there is no real need to change the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make an AJAX request to any directory on the hard drive.

Unless your web root is your desktop that file will never be served.

Move `tester excel.csv` into your webroot and request it with a URL, not a file path.

You should also learn how to use your web console so you don't have to post questions about a library when your real problem is that you're getting a 404.

Comment: I used the direct file path to get to my csv, but how would you add it into my webroot or request it with a URL

Comment: You have to put the file onto your web server and then use its URL to get it with an AJAX call.